# C11 : killing a thread using standard-only library

Tags: multithreading, standards, c11

How does one go about killing a thread in C using the functions provided in `<threads.h>`? There seems to be no *direct* way of doing this.  Note: I'm aware that pthreads provides a `pthread_cancel()` function but I would like to stick to `<threads.h>` functions.

Comment: If you allow one thread to forcibly kill another, how can you guarantee that the kill does not happen at some crucial moment where the victim thread has not left a mess that other threads will be unable to clean up?

Comment: I want to second what @SolomonSlow said -- there is almost never a justification to unilaterally kill a thread.  If you find yourself wanting/needing to do that, then you should instead find a way to tell the thread to voluntarily (and cleanly) exit, so that you can `pthread_join()` it and clean things up reliably.  If for some reason that isn't possible, then your next best bet is to spawn a child *process* rather than a child *thread*, since a child *process* can be unilaterally killed and the OS will clean up its resources for you.

Comment: None of my threads in this particular application is using resources (other than thrd_t).

Comment: @tkf - I don't think that helps.  The (other) hard problems of killing threads typically arise when threads may be updating variables or data structures shared with other threads, or when they are coordinating this other threads via some kind of wait / notify mechanism.  In the first case, the thread may be killed in the process of doing an update.  In the second, other threads could get stuck waiting for a notification from the killed thread.

Comment: As stated in the answer there is no such interface, and there are good reasons for it. Getting the concept of killing threads right is a nightmare, and POSIX thread implementations have 90% of their complexity and code just to enable this feature. All gets more complicated: mutexes, condition variables, and synchronization feature then has to have knobs to know what to do if a thread disapears that holds locks or was in the middle of communicating something.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

It's trivial to enumerate the 8 functions defined by the C11 standard for `<threads.h>`, iterate through them and determine that none of them does what you want.

Therefore, as written, your requirements cannot be met. If that is all you care about, then you can stop reading here.

---

If you care about practical solutions, then it depends on what *actual* problem you're trying to solve:

- If you have a thread stuck somewhere in code that you wrote, then you simply add an `_Atomic` variable and check it repeatedly. This is pretty much what `pthread_cancel` is doing anyway.
- If you have a thread stuck somewhere in code that you call into but have no control over, then you need existing synchronisation points. If the code you call into uses the syscalls that `pthread_cancel` declares to be synchronisation points, then you can use that. If not, then you'll have to make use of preemption and that goes into OS-specific territory. On POSIX systems, you can mask a given signal on all threads except the target, and when that signal is raised, it will by necessity be raised on the target thread. Lower-level APIs might exist to remove threads from the scheduling pool and clean up their kernel state, but that will not clean up their userland state. And despite your claim that, in your case, they are "not using resources", there will at the very least be a stack to clean up, and very likely also `thrd_*`-API bookkeeping data.
- If you have a thread stuck in kernel mode, then there is absolutely nothing you can do. There is no god, not even `SIGKILL` will save you, no kernel could ever sanely recover from killing a thread with an active call stack in the kernel, all you can do is pull the power chord.